# How to pad zeroes to a substring in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a varchar type column having text like `20171126-401-9-4496`. 
The string has 4 sections with the fixed length for each section:

Section 1 - 8 digits

Section 2 - 4 digits

Section 3 - 2 digits

Section 4 - 4 digits

I would like to pad 2nd and 3rd section of the string with a '0'so that the text becomes
`20171126-0401-09-4496` which satisfies the fixed length requirement of each section. I tried with `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX` functions but was unable to get the desired result. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Post your attempt with substring and charindex, and the error you got, so we can debug it.  Should a zero always be added, or does it depend on the data in the string?

Comment: what if there was already a 0 there?

Comment: @scsimon updated my question.

Comment: Good thing, because that makes it a WAY different question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What a perfect time for a `PARSENAME` hack!

```
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(MyColumn,'-','.'),4)+'-'+
       RIGHT('0000'+PARSENAME(REPLACE(MyColumn,'-','.'),3),4)+'-'+
       RIGHT('00'+PARSENAME(REPLACE(MyColumn,'-','.'),2),2)+'-'+
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(MyColumn,'-','.'),1)
```

Comment: this is reversed when i run it oddly enough. but i like the use of parsename

Comment: added a deleted answer with changes. I'd just add the condition for the first and last columns too for fun

Comment: I don't use parsename often enough.  I keep forgetting that the sections are numbered in descending order.  Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to insert a '0' on those positions then it will work like that:

```
select stuff (stuff('20171126-401-9-4496',14,0,0),10,0,'0')
```

[image]

If we have a variable length of fields then it will work like this (example for the first field):

```
select @str = '20175555-0001-9-46'

select @len =  (select charindex('-',substring(@str,10,100)))

select
case 
when @len = 2 
then stuff(@str,10,0,'000')
when @len = 3 
then stuff(@str,10,0,'00')
when @len = 4 
then stuff(@str,10,0,'0')
else
@str
end as string
```

Comment: this is close but doesn't work for, say, ''20175555-1-9-46''

Comment: @scsimon I've updated my answer for variable length, example is for the first. field

Answer (score 1):

Taking on what Tab Allemen did, you can apply it to the first and last columns as well...

```
declare @var varchar(18) = '201711-1-9-4496'


SELECT right('00000000' + parsename(replace(@var,'-','.'),4),8) + '-'
        + right('0000' + parsename(replace(@var,'-','.'),3),4) + '-'
        + right('00' + parsename(replace(@var,'-','.'),2),2) + '-'
        + right('0000' + parsename(replace(@var,'-','.'),1),4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really love derived tables...

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE (mynewstring varchar(100)) --replace @mytable with your table name

INSERT INTO @mytable VALUES 
 ('20171126-401-9-4496')
,('1-401-9-4496')
,('1-1-1-1')
,('---')

SELECT dT4.FirstVal + SecondVal + ThirdVal + FourthVal [newval]
  FROM (
SELECT LEFT('00000000', len('00000000') - (dT3.[firstD] - 1)) + LEFT(mynewstring, [firstD]) [FirstVal]
      ,LEFT('0000', len('0000') - ([secondD] - [firstD] - 1)) + SUBSTRING(mynewstring, [firstD] + 1, [secondD] - [firstD]) [SecondVal]
      ,LEFT('00', len('00') - ([thirdD] - [secondD] - 1)) + SUBSTRING(mynewstring, [secondD] + 1, [thirdD] - [secondD]) [ThirdVal]
      ,LEFT('0000', len('0000') - (len(mynewstring) - [thirdD])) + SUBSTRING(mynewstring, [thirdD] + 1, len(mynewstring) - [thirdD]) [FourthVal]
  FROM (
SELECT dT2.*
      ,CHARINDEX('-', dT2.mynewstring, dT2.[secondD] + 1) [thirdD]
  FROM (
SELECT dT.*
      ,CHARINDEX('-', dT.mynewstring, dT.[firstD]+1) [secondD]
  FROM (
SELECT mynewstring  
      ,CHARINDEX('-', mynewstring, 0) [firstD]    
  FROM @mytable
       ) AS dT      
       ) AS dT2
       ) AS dT3
       ) AS dT4
```

Would produce output:

```
newval
20171126-0401-09-4496
00000001-0401-09-4496
00000001-0001-01-0001
00000000-0000-00-0000
```

The algorithm grabs the position of the dashes, sequentially.  It then does string concatenation with 0's for that position. Finally, the values are concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

To round out and show a split string method in case someone looks at this question and has 5 or more parts when parsename hack wont work.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (col1 VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
    ('20171127-4301-9-4496'),('20171125-301-9-4496'),('20171124-21-9-4496'),('20171123-1-9-4496'),('20171122-1-09-4496')

SELECT
    *
    ,NewFormat = p1 + '-' + RIGHT('0000' + P2, 4) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + P3,2) + '-' + P4
FROM
    (
       SELECT col1, xmlcol1 = CAST(('<row><col>' + REPLACE(col1,'-','</col><col>') + '</col></row>') AS XML)
       FROM
          @Table 
    ) t
    CROSS APPLY
       (SELECT
          t.n.value('col[1]','VARCHAR(50)') as P1
          ,t.n.value('col[2]','VARCHAR(50)') as P2
          ,t.n.value('col[3]','VARCHAR(50)') as P3
          ,t.n.value('col[4]','VARCHAR(50)') as P4
        FROM
          t.xmlcol1.nodes ('/row') AS t(n)) c
```

You can also extend so that you can test if the part of the string has more than 4 characters etc and not pad it or what ever.